# Why does my Code in C for Inserting a Node Into A Binary search Tree Delete Some of the Other Nodes Inserted?

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have tried everything to figure out what is wrong with my code. I tried to search for the problem. I tried to redo the code. I even tried to simulate the code several times on a piece of paper and It should work fine. But it's not. So far the code works when I input a root as 5, then add another node for example 8, then add another node 9, then add another node 6. But when I try to add another node for example 3. When I try to display all the nodes, the Node 6 and 9 are gone. But the node 3 was added. Any help would be appreciated.

```
bool addrec(nd *root,nd *tp,nd *tr,nd *data)//FIX ADDING
{
    nd temp;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    temp->bkNumber=(*data)->bkNumber;
    strcpy(temp->bkTitle, (*data)->bkTitle);
    strcpy(temp->bkAuthor, (*data)->bkAuthor);
    temp->bkCopyright=(*data)->bkCopyright; 

    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right=NULL;
    bool added=false;

    if(*root==NULL)
    {
        *root=temp;
        added=true;    
    }
    else
    {
        *tp=*root;
        while(*tp!=NULL)
        {
            *tr=*tp;
            if((*tp)->bkNumber>=(*data)->bkNumber)
                *tp=(*tp)->left;
            else
                *tp=(*tp)->right;
        }
        if((*tr)->bkNumber>=(*data)->bkNumber)
        {
            (*tr)->left=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            (*tr)->right=temp;
        }
        added=true;
        if((*tr)->right==NULL)//House Keeping To Make Sure the pointers of the new node is pointing to NULL
        {
            *tr=(*tr)->left;
            (*tr)->left=NULL;
            (*tr)->right=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            *tr=(*tr)->right;
            (*tr)->left=NULL;
            (*tr)->right=NULL;
        }
    }
    data=NULL;
    temp=NULL;
    *tr=NULL;
    *tp=NULL;
    return added;
}
```

Comment: What are tp and tr ? why do you send them ? 
Do you dynamically allocate them before ?

Comment: tp and tr are initialized to NULL when I sent them,so they are pointing to NULL,I sent them so I can use them in the function addrec, so that I don't have to declare more local variables, tp and tr are used also in my other functions for searching and deleteing.